# How do I solve $x^5 +x^3+x = y$ for $x$?

Tags: functions, polynomials, inverse

I understand how to solve quadratics, but I do not know how to approach this question. Could anyone show me a step by step solution expression $x$ in terms of $y$?

The explicit question out of the book is to find $f^{-1}(3)$ for $f(x) = x^5 +x^3+x$

So far I have reduced $x^5 +x^3+x = y$ to $y/x - 3/4 = (x^2 + 1/2)^2$ or $y = x((x^2+1/2)^2 + 3/4)$ but Im still just as lost.

Comment: Are you sure it can be solved?

Comment: you mean $x^5+x^3+x=0$?

Comment: What mathlove has suggested is indeed solvable

Comment: I believe it can be solved, as my calculus book is asking for the inverse of the functions. I mean exactly what i wrote.

Comment: Maybe your calculus book is asking you to show that the function $x^5+x^3+x$ **has** an inverse.  We can show that without producing an explicit formula for the inverse function.

Comment: Andre you may be right, but I can't tell you for sure as I don't have access to the book right now. If that were the case, how would you prove that the function has an inverse without explicitly finding it?

Comment: Each of $x$, $x^3$, and $x^5$ is strictly increasing; so their sum is strictly increasing. Thus, your function is one-to-one.

Comment: The uniqueness is by the fact the function is increasing. The fact that for any $y$ there is an $x$ goes like this. Take e.g. $y=47$. Note that $f(0)\lt 47$ and $f(100)\gt 47$. So since $f$ is continuous, by the Intermediate Value Theorem there is an $x$ such that $f(x)$ is exactly $47$.

Comment: FWIW, your question title (invert $y = x^{5} + x^{3} + x = f(x)$) does not match the question body (find $f^{-1}(3)$, which is _much_ easier). It's possible this mismatch has caused some confusion.

Answer (score 4):

To show that for any $b$ there is an $a$  such that $f(a)=b$ we can proceed like this.

The result is obvious if $b=0$. Now let $b\gt 0$. We show there is an $a$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Note that $f(0)\lt b$ and $f(b)\gt b$. So by the Intermediate Value Theorem, because $f$ is continuous, there is an $a$ between $0$ and $b$ such that $f(a)=b$.

A similar argument deals with negative $b$, or else we can use the fact that $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Uniqueness is dealt with in comments and other answers.

Comment: Alight, I can work with this. I found that $f(1)=3$. In order to prove this is unique, can I use the first derivative test to show that the function is always increasing, thus for all $a>1$ necessarily means $f(a)>3$ and for all $a<1$ necessarily means $f(a)<3$?

This sounds logical to me. Do you agree?

Comment: In addition to proving that the value $a$ st $f(a)=3$ is unique, is it also necessary to prove that $f^-1$ exists to prove that $f^-1(3)=a$?

Comment: For the particular case $f(a)=3$, existence is not an issue at all, since it is obvious by inspection that $f(1)=3$. For uniqueness, $f'(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$, so the function is increasing, and therefore there cannot be two different solutions of $f(x)=3$.  For **general** values of $b$, we can usually not spot a solution. We can't find a solution "by formula" either, because there is no general formula for solving degree $5$ equations.

Answer (score 2):

Can you think of a value of $a$ so that $f(a) = 3$?  Try plugging in some values of $a$ and see what you get.

If this value is unique (which is true, but we need to verify it), then we write $a = f^{-1} (3)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be necessary to prove that $f^-1$ exists in order to write that $a=f^−1(3)$. To show that a function has an inverse, it is equivelent to say that it is one-to-one. And to prove that it is one-to-one, we much prove that $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $a=b$. In other words, assume $a^5+a^3+a = b^5+b^3+b$ and reduce it to $a=b$. But that's just as hard as solving $y=x^5+x^3+x$ for x!

Answer (score 2):

A few of the answers suggest guessing the answer by inspection. Indeed, in most calculus problems that could be on an exam it is very likely that the solution to the polynomial is meant to be 'obvious', frequently one of $0,\pm1,\pm2$. This is just to keep numbers and computations reasonable, but is not an absolute guarantee (especially if you get to use a calculator). The mantra is usually "the uglier it looks, the more likely it is that there is a simple answer and argument."

But there's also a formal justification. Our first hope would be for a rational solution to $f(x)=3$. Sounds like a lot of possibilities, right? But by the [rational roots theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the only possibilities here are $\pm1,\pm3$. That's a nice, small list, and it's easy to verify that one of these actually works, thus solving the problem.

If there wasn't a rational root we'd be stuck with a more problematic situation, but it's always a good idea to check for predictable, nice answers first, especially when it involves so little effort to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find $f^{-1}(3)=x$ for some $x$. We can apply the function to both sides giving us $3=f(a)$ now we need to find $x^5+x^3+x=3\implies x^5+x^3+x-3=0$. There are many ways to solve this however you can go ahead and guess that one solution would be $x=1$. Now we can perform polynomial division on $x^5+x^3+x-3$ by dividing by $x-1$ as that is a root and we get $x^4+x^3+2x^2+3$. The rest of your roots are there however it seems they are not real.

---

There is almost an art to guessing however one way to get a good feel is to try and plot the graph for different values. I guessed 1 because there were 3 terms with no coefficients and they evaluate to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the quality of previous answers and comments, my answer will probably be stupid.

If you want $x$ such that $$f(x)=x^5 +x^3+x - y=0$$ you could just apply iteratively Newton which will give as the simplest $$x_{n+1}=\frac{4 x_n^5+2 x_n^3+y}{5 x_n^4+3 x_n^2+1}$$ which could be considered as a recursive definition of the inverse of $y$.

Assuming $y>1$, starting with $x_0=y^{\frac{1}{5}}$ (since, for this value $f(x_0) >0$ and $f''(x_0)> 0$) the process will converge without any overshoot of the solution.

Let me try with $y=10^{10}$ so $x_0=100$; the successive iterates are $x_1=99.99799992$, $x_2=99.99799984$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Let me try with $y=10^{5}$ so $x_0=10$; the successive iterates are $x_1=9.979920876$, $x_2=9.979839999$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Solving it for a general $y$ will be difficult, but solving for $y=0$ is more doable.

If $x^5+x^3+x=0$, then because the left hand side is divisible by $x$, either $x=0$ or we can divide by $x$ to get $(x^2)^2+x^2+1=0$.  This is a quadratic in $x^2$, so by the quadratic formula, $x^2=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}.$

Thus, the five solutions are $x=0$ and $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}}$.

---

If we want to show that the function is invertible, then because polynomial functions are continuous, it is enough to show that the function is either always increasing or always decreasing.  Because polynomial functions are continuously differentiable and polynomials cannot be locally constant without being completely constant, this is equivalent to showing that the first derivative is always non-negative or always non-positive.

The derivative is $5(x^2)^2+3(x^2)+1$.  Because $x^2\geq 0$ for all $x$, the derivative is always positive (in fact, always at least $1$), and therefore the function must be invertible.

Comment: The problem comes from my calculus book and it is asking for the inverse function of the one I originally wrote, so I assume it's solvable as the book is asking for a solution. It doesn't make sense to me that the book would ask a trick question.

Comment: Does it ask or the inverse function, or to show that the function has an inverse?  The latter question can be done by considering the derivative and showing that it has no real roots.  Off the top of my head, I don't know ANY way to actually invert a function like this.

Comment: I am not sure as I don't have access to the book right now. For my own curiosity, would you mind explaining to me how to prove such a function has an inverse?

Comment: First derivative test

Comment: I thought the first derivative was to determine local maxima and minima by showing where the slope changes from negative to positive or vice versa.

What does the first derivative tell you about the function's inverse?

Comment: @Brandon Here, the first derivative is always positive. So, the function is strictly increasing. So...

Comment: Suppose that a (continuous, differentiable) function had no inverse.  Then for some $a, b$, we would have $f(a)=f(b)$.  By Rolle's theorem (special case of the MVT), we could find a place on the interval $[a,b]$ where the derivative was zero.  If the derivative is NEVER zero, we must have that an inverse exists.  It is still possible to have a function that always increases but has zero derivative somewhere (which is why I used the language I did in my answer), but an always increasing function never takes the same value twice.

Answer (score 0):

How about we compute the inverse using the inverse function theorem?

The inverse function theorem tells us that if $f$ is differentiable and invertible, then $(f^{-1})'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$.  Your $f$ satisfies both those properties (as others have shown, it is strictly increasing and so injective and so invertible).

So we compute

$$
  f'(x) = 5x^4 + 3x^2 + 1 
$$

And we know that:

$$
  (f^{-1})'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{5x^4 + 3x^2 + 1} 
$$

Finally, we also know two things.  $f^{-1}$ is "the" anti-derivative of $(f^{-1})'$ (footnote 1) and

$$
  \int (f^{-1})'(x)\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

can be done by u-substitution.

But this is where I'm stopping, since I've been out of calculus for so long. :)

[1]: in this case, it matters that there isn't a unique anti-derivative.  You will need to solve for the one with the correct constant $C$.  And it is essential that you do so.  Only the one with the correct constant is an inverse for $f$.  The necessity to solve for the correct $C$ means that this method won't work on the general quintic, but it will work on this one.  You do have enough information, since you can actually factor this quintic.

Comment: No matter how you phrase it: you are trying to solve a 5'th degree equation. I don't see how this can help. Calculus is not magic! If you do this for a general equation $x^5 + ax^4 + \ldots = 0$, why should it not work (and we know from Abel that it cannot work)?

Comment: @Winther: Did you not notice that an $x$ factors out of the quintic immediately?  It's $x(x^4 + x^2 + 1)$, *not* a general quintic.  We couldn't use this method for the general quintic because we can't factor the general quintic to find the anti-derivative that satisfies the original equation.  But I didn't make any claims about the general quintic.  I made a claim about *this* quintic.

Comment: It would be nice if this works, but I still don't see it. Your LHS is $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))$ so your integral is $\int \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x)) dx = \int \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x^5 + x^3 + x) dx$ not $\int \frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)dx$. Here comes the point: if you are to make a substitution $u = x^5 + x^3 + x$ to solve it then it requires you to invert this equation to get $x(u)$. But this is the same problem as we are trying to solve!

Comment: But we have $\int g(x) dx = \int g(h(x)) h'(x) dx$ for any differentiable $h$.  This is the fact that bridges the integral we want and the integral we have.  Or am I missing something here?  Like I said, it has been a long time since calculus.  I know we do have all of those quantities.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^5+x^3+x-3=0\\(x^5-1)+(x^3-1)+(x-1)=0\\(x-1)(x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2x+3)=0$$
So the solution you wanted is $x=1$.
Sorry but it is just a solution ad hoc.